# TSQL Join Issue with Multiple Records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a large query I am using to pull in stats about various projects a person is working on. One piece of this is pulling in the number of hours a person will be training classes this week.

```
COALESCE ((SELECT    Cast(s.nonprodhrs AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS '@count'
                                FROM     dbo.BS_TrainingEvent_Segments AS s
                                INNER JOIN dbo.BS_Training_Trainers AS tr
                                ON tr.segmentID = s.teSegmentID
                                WHERE s.segmentDate >= @StartOfWeek AND s.segmentDate <= @EndOfWeek
                                AND tr.trainerEmpID = t.EmpID
                                ), 0) AS '@hoursThisWeek'
```

The issue I am running into is the inner join on the `Training_Trainers` table. There are multiple records with the same `segmentID` which is throwing the error `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows`.

Is there another way I can accomplish this without the join or tweak it in a way where it works correctly?

Comment: Maybe you can use "select ... from Segments where exists (select 1 from Trainers.." -kind of structure here instead of the join?

Comment: As you say, there are multiple records that can be returned by your subquery.   Change your query so that it only returns the one record that your business rules dictate it should return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about what you are doing, but try this. It looks like you just want sum of hours:

`Cast(SUM(s.nonprodhrs) AS DECIMAL(10, 2))....`

Comment: Well the hours works fine, I can get that where there is a single segment. Its join that is the problem. Its joining on a `segmentID` but the table its joining on has multiple instances of the same `segmentID` which is why it throws the error

Comment: I don't know what is segment, what is trainer, why there are many segments, why you are joining those tables at all. I don't know your data, I don't know you desired output. I just know that `Subquery won't let you return more than 1 value`. That's why I suggest you to aggregate data in your subquery in order to get just one value.

Comment: I think George is right. Since you are trying to find the numbers of hours someone spends in training classes(multiple) you should use SUM() to add up all the hours for a total. You might want CAST() to decimal and then SUM if precision is important.